How do I fill this pdf form fields using itext7? zero acroForm.GetAllFormFields and zero page.GetAnnotations
BOIR pdf: https://boiefiling.fincen.gov/c8576e94532490750200.pdf
When I open the pdf in Adobe Reader there are four pages but when I use itext7, I get only one page using pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages.
Also acroForm.GetAllFormFields gets zero form fields even though there are many fillable form fields when I open it in Adobe Reader.
Dim acroForm As PdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, False)
Dim fields As Commons.Utils.LinkedDictionary(Of String, Forms.Fields.PdfFormField) = acroForm.GetAllFormFields

Finally, page.GetAnnotations returns zero annotations which is really odd.
Imports System.IO
Imports iText.Kernel.Pdf
Imports iText.Forms
Imports iText.Forms.Fields

Public Shared Sub FixUnregisteredFormFields(pdfPath As String, outputPdfPath As String)

    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfPath)
    Dim pdfWriter As New PdfWriter(outputPdfPath)
    Dim pdfDoc As New PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter)

    Dim root As PdfCatalog = pdfDoc.GetCatalog
    Dim form As PdfDictionary = root.GetPdfObject().GetAsDictionary(PdfName.AcroForm)
    Dim fields As PdfArray = form.GetAsArray(PdfName.Fields)

    For pageNumber As Integer = 1 To pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages()
        Dim page As PdfPage = pdfDoc.GetPage(pageNumber)
        Dim annotations = page.GetAnnotations
        For Each annotation As PdfAnnotation In annotations
            fields.Add(annotation.GetPdfObject)
        Next
    Next
    pdfDoc.Close()
End Sub
'https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/why-are-the-acrofields-in-my-document-empty

Normally we use this to fill the form fields, but it doesn't work for this pdf since there aren't any fields found by GetAllFormFields.
Dim fields As Commons.Utils.LinkedDictionary(Of String, Forms.Fields.PdfFormField) = form.GetAllFormFields
For Each item In ListItems
    Dim fld As PdfFormField = Nothing
    If fields.TryGetValue(item.FieldName, fld) Then
        fld.SetValue(item.Value)
    End If
Next

How do I fill this pdf form fields using itext7?

@KJ "This question is similar to: Programatically fill Government PDF (XFA dynamic)." Thanks so much for that link. Very helpful!

The other option is to efile the form. That's probably what we end up doing.
